# php - How can I create dynamic urls for my language dictionary entries

Tags: php, mysql

I am a new learner in web development and have a language dictionary that works fine. However, I want to be able to create dynamic urls for SEO or search engine issues. For the last two days, I have been trying various approaches, including those given in stackoverflow.com, to adapt my existing codes, but unfortunately no success until now.

Well, I have two files: dictionary.php and gb-tr.php.

In dictionary.php, I have the following code block to start the query:

```
$('#gsearchsimple').bind("input", function() {
var query = $('#gsearchsimple').val();
    if (query.length > 3) {
        $.ajax({
            url:"gb-tr.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{query:query},
            success:function(data)
                {$('.list-group').html(data);}
        }); } });
```

The query posted to the gb-tr.php file is handled with the following code block in gb-tr.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['query']))
{
    $query = "
    SELECT DISTINCT Turkish FROM gbtr 
    WHERE Turkish LIKE '%".trim($_POST["query"])."%'
    ORDER BY length(Turkish) asc
    LIMIT 20
    ";

    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    $output = '';

    foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $output .= '
            <li class="list-group-item contsearch">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="gsearch" id="list" style="color:#333;text-decoration:none; outline: none;">'.$row["Turkish"].'</a>
            </li>
            ';
        }

    echo $output;
}
```

Then, dictionary.php shows the list generated by the above code, and when I click on one entry from the list with the following code block in dictionary.php:

```
$(document).on('click', '.gsearch', function(){
var edata = $(this).text();
$('#gsearchsimple').val(edata);
$('.list-group').css('display', 'none');
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 200);
    $.ajax({
        url:"gb-tr.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{edata:edata},
        success:function(data)
            {
                $('#detail').html(data);
            }
    }); });
```

the clicked entry is handled in gb-tr.php with the following code block:

```
if(isset($_POST['edata']))
{
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM gbtr 
    WHERE English = '".trim($_POST["edata"])."' or Turkish = '".trim($_POST["edata"])."' 
    LIMIT 5
    ";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

    echo '
    <table id="hide-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th class="table-font-800" width="50%">English</th>
            <th class="table-font-800" width="50%">Turkish</th>
        </tr>
    </table>';

    foreach($result as $row) {

    echo '<table id="hide-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>';
    echo '<th class="table-font-100" width="50%">'.$row["English"].'</th>';
    echo '<th class="table-font-100" width="50%">'.$row["Turkish"].'</th>';
    echo '</tr>';


    echo '</table>';
        
    }
}
```

and I get the result in the dictionary.php page in the following div container:

```
<div id="detail" style="margin-top:16px; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -ms-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto;"></div>
```

So far, I don't have any problem and everything works fine.

But for dynamic url generation, I have tried to modify the following code in gb-tr.php

```
foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $output .= '
            <li class="list-group-item contsearch">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="gsearch" id="list" style="color:#333;text-decoration:none; outline: none;">'.$row["Turkish"].'</a>
            </li>
            ';
        }
```

as

```
<a href="?Turkish='.$row["Turkish"].'" class="gsearch" id="list" style="color:#333;text-decoration:none; outline: none;">'.$row["Turkish"].'</a>
```

Now I can see the generated link with the variables when I hover on the relevant entry. But once I click it I get the result for a moment and then it goes away and land at the starting page with the generated url.

Can someone help me please solve my problem. I thank you in advance for reading my question.

Comment: The problem is that clicking the link now causes a new URL to load (because you have an actual URL in the href attribute now, instead of just the "do nothing" JavaScript statement you had in there before), so the current page is replaced with a new one. You need to suppress the default action of clicking a link, in your click handler. (Although the question would be, why you care about the URLs in this context in the first place - if you are using AJAX to load the data in the background? You likely don't want any search engine to make that same request anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default action, of following the link, when you handle a click on a link with Javascript. In your code that would look like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.gsearch', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  <... other stuff ...>
});
```

See: [Event.preventDefault();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Of course you would now also have to think of the case where Javascript is disabled and you actually have to react to the link that was clicked. Remember that search engines will follow your link and expect sensible results.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I tried your advise, it works in that I can land on the results page but the link is not as expected, i.e. has no variables.